# Converting json to DataFrame error 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

Tags: json, dataframe

I extract from an API a sort of values, seems to be a json list. I need to convert it to a Pandas DataFrame and I have teh folowing error 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str'. If I print type(), the result is a List, but the format seems to be json. I do not understand. Thanks a los for any help.
The script is as folow:
respuesta = requestResponse.json()
type(respuesta) -> List
df = pd.json_normalize(respuesta['priceData'], meta=['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'volumeNotional', 'tradesDone'], max_level=0)

respuesta = requestResponse.json()
print(respuesta)

This is the response from API.

[{'ticker': 'btcusd',
'baseCurrency': 'btc',
'quoteCurrency': 'usd',
'priceData': [{'date': '2019-01-02T00:00:00+00:00',
'open': 3914.749407813885,
'high': 3942.374263716895,
'low': 3846.1755315352952,
'close': 3849.1217299601617,
'volume': 339.6752801089,
'volumeNotional': 1307451.5017974717,
'tradesDone': 754.0},
{'date': '2019-01-02T00:05:00+00:00',
'open': 3877.9808356573753,
'high': 3959.2897083203065,
'low': 3854.627629862284,
'close': 3952.9165201165983,
'volume': 196.80303629,
'volumeNotional': 777945.9733598474,
'tradesDone': 350.0},
{'date': '2019-01-02T00:10:00+00:00',
'open': 3839.831999545506,
'high': 3958.953010556605,
'low': 3832.686959636753,
'close': 3948.518287275088,
'volume': 221.4793399562,
...
'close': 3807.3247302129353,
'volume': 84.32994581,
'volumeNotional': 321071.48817992967,
'tradesDone': 631.0},
...]}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests



# fake data 
respuesta = [{'ticker': 'btcusd', 'baseCurrency': 'btc', 'quoteCurrency': 'usd', 'priceData': [{'date': '2019-01-02T00:00:00+00:00', 'open': 3914.749407813885, 'high': 3942.374263716895, 'low': 3846.1755315352952, 'close': 3849.1217299601617, 'volume': 339.6752801089, 'volumeNotional': 1307451.5017974717, 'tradesDone': 754.0}, {'date': '2019-01-02T00:05:00+00:00', 'open': 3877.9808356573753, 'high': 3959.2897083203065, 'low': 3854.627629862284, 'close': 3952.9165201165983, 'volume': 196.80303629, 'volumeNotional': 777945.9733598474, 'tradesDone': 350.0}, ...]}]

# Correcting the access to 'priceData'
price_data = respuesta[0]['priceData']

# Normalizing 'priceData'
df = pd.json_normalize(price_data)

print(df.head())  # Just to check the first few rows
```